# one page landscape mode swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make only ONE view in my application on landscape mode when the device changes its position, -not from the beginning. And that the rest of the views work in portrait.

> AppDelegate

```
internal var shouldRotate = false  
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return shouldRotate ? .allButUpsideDown : .portrait
    }
```

> viewDidLoad

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate      
appDelegate.shouldRotate = true
```

This works but it applies to all my pages and I only want one in particular

Answer (score 1):

In the view controller that you want to be landscape-only, override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and provide an `OptionSet` of landscape:

```
public override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [.landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight]
}
```